# Is it possible to connect two IPSec site-to-site VPNs to one Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

I need to connect to two IPSEC site to site vpns from a Windows 2008 Server at the same time. Is it posible?

I tried to assign two IP Security Policies, but it seems I can only have one assigned at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get one policy active at a time but you can create many filters under the policy.  See [Creating and Using IPsec Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730656.aspx)